# Oracle Connections from c#

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, winforms

I have dynamic dashboard and every 3 seconds gets 20 query from oracle to c# winforms.

Currently I use like below;

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(oradb);
con.Open();
OracleCommand cmd1 = new OracleCommand(getSystime, con);
OracleDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
dr1.Read();
.
.
.
.
.
.
OracleCommand cmd15 = new OracleCommand(getSqltime, con);
OracleDataReader dr15 = cmd15.ExecuteReader();
dr15.Read();

con.Dispose();
con.Close();
```

Currently when i check, The application has 9 inactive sessions and there are almost 100 open cursor about it. The numbers are not increasing. Even if i check after 1 hour, there are 9 active/inactive and almost 100 open_cursor from my application.

This will be my first application and so i don't have any experience on it.

How can i interpret it ?

Comment: I guess the OracleCommand implements the IDisposable interface which lets u wrap the code in a using statement and then u be sure it will be disposed after it has finished

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Could you please write as an answer using my above code and i can accept that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always `Close()` the `OracleDataReader` after you have read the content. And surround it by `using {}` as it implements `IDisposable`

```
using ( OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(oradb) ) {
   con.Open();
   OracleCommand cmd1 = new OracleCommand(getSystime, con);
   using ( OracleDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader() ) {
      dr1.Read();
      ...
      dr1.Close();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question but
Try using

OracleDataAdapter

instead of

OracleDataReader

My understanding is that DataReader is faster than DataAdapter, but DataReader works in connected mode. DataAdapter/DataSet works in disconnected mode.

This could be the reason you're not getting your queries after a certain amount of time.